# Validating a date without knowing its format

Tags: php, validation, date, datetime, language-agnostic

I'm working on date validation for a validation library.  A date format and a variable containing the date to validate will be supplied to the library.

```
$validator->validate( $_POST['date'], 'm/d/y' );
```

It's pretty easy to do basic validation with `DateTime::createFromFormat()`

```
if ( DateTime::createFromFormat( $format, $date ) !== false ) {
    // "valid" date
}
```

My issue is that with this method invalid dates such as 23/23/23 pass because the `DateTime` class will shift the date and set it to 2024-11-23.  I know of the existence of `checkdate()` but without knowing the format I can't see a way to extract the origin month/day/year.

Any ideas on how to validate a date like this?

Comment: Any chance to limit down the variants of possible date strings?

Comment: @axel.michel - i'd rather not

Comment: If you don't know the format then you will get ambiguities.  Is 1/2/13 1 February (European format) or 2 January (US format)?  You can unambiguously resolve some, like 23/9/13, but the first 12 days of each month are giong to be ambiguous.  That doesn't count dates that start with a 2 digit year: 13/1/2 = 2 January 2013.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you don't know the format of the date then you should use `date_parse`

> [date_parse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php) — Returns associative array with detailed info about given date

**Example**

```
print_r(date_parse("23/23/23 00:14:38"));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [year] => 2023
    [month] => 3            <------------------- Attempts to correct month 
    [day] => 23
    [hour] => 0
    [minute] => 14
    [second] => 38
    [fraction] => 0
    [warning_count] => 0
    [warnings] => Array
        (
        )

    [error_count] => 1
    [errors] => Array
        (
            [0] => Unexpected character        <----- add errors found 
        )

    [is_localtime] => 
)
```

Simple Class

```
$date = "23/3/2013 00:14:38";
if (DateTimeParse::createFromString($date) !== false) {
    // "valid" date
}
```

Class Used

```
class DateTimeParse {

    public static function createFromString($string) {
        $date = date_parse(str_replace("/", "-", $string));
        if ($date['error_count'] > 0)
            return false;
        $date = sprintf("%d-%d-%d %d:%d:%d", $date['year'], $date['month'], $date['day'], $date['hour'], $date['minute'], $date['second']);
        return \DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d g:i:s", $date);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think his question is not exactly about 23/23/23...how about 10/10/10 without knowing its format

Comment: Seems as if checking that there are no warnings or errors returned from date_parse does the trick.

Comment: @Galen don't forget to convert `/` to `-` .. When working with `date_parse` it works better with `-` and `:`